# Pixel searcher on a photo

Tags: c#

I've got some photos that I want to do some fun things with.

For example, I've got this one pohto with lots of colours blended in, and I want to be able to dissect the photo into pixels and to check what colour each pixel is, so I can hold record of exactly what colour is used the most in the photo.

Is there any library built in that I can use that has the capacity to dissect such a photo and iterate through every pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your images with [`Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If they are small, you can call [`Bitmap.GetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a loop. If they are big, more than a few megapixels I guess, it will be very slow, then you should use [`Bitmap.LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. All links have samples. You can use a `Dictionary` collection to build a histogram, just be careful because similar pixels will have slightly different R, G and B values, so your collection might grow incredibly huge.

Answer (score 0):

Load the image into an BitMap then process the bitmap using [GetPixel method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) which returns a Color object

```
  private void GetPixel_Example(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    // Create a Bitmap object from an image file.
    Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("Grapes.jpg");
    int width = myBitmap.Width;
    int height = myBitmap.Height;


    // Get the color of a pixel within myBitmap.

    for (int widthIndex = 0;widthIndex < width;widthIndex++) 
    {
        for (int heightIndex = 0;heightIndex < height;heightIndex ++) 
        {
              Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(widthIndex, heightIndex);
              // add to dictionary
        }
    }
    // Fill a rectangle with pixelColor.
    SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(pixelColor);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
```

You can use a dictionary to store the colour and the count